# Returning invalid data from RegQueryValueEx() DWORD

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to read a DWORD value from the registry. In the registry, it's stored as 0x00000068 (104).  When I read the value from the registry, I'm getting a very large number (3435973836).  Any help is appreciated!

```
DWORD getRecentId(PDWORD id) {
    HKEY hKey;

    LONG lRes = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, _T("SOFTWARE\\My App\\Feed Reader"), 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey);

    if (!lRes == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKey);

        return ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND;
    }

    DWORD dwSize = sizeof(DWORD);

    lRes = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, _T("Latest"), NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)&id, &dwSize);

    if (!lRes == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        RegCloseKey(hKey);

        return ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY;
    }

    RegCloseKey(hKey);

    return lRes;
}
```

Comment: Don't take the address of id, it's already a pointer. Use (LPBYTE)id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3435973836 is a magic number.  Convert it to hex to get 0xcccccccc.  When you see that back in the Visual Studio debugger then you *know* that you are using an uninitialized variable.

It is, using `&id` was wrong.  That alters the pointer, not the pointed-to value.  Use `id` instead.